# Planting a pot bound Acer in the ground in June

Tags: planting, maple

can I plant a pot bound Acer- about 5 feet tall - into the garden now it's June? ( this is in the UK by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but only if you observe one rule - you must water the soil directly round the base of the trunk with 5-10 litres of water about every five days, essentially a couple of watering cans full. If it all runs off a fair distance because the soil is dry, you will need to give twice as much. Unless, that is, we have a period of torrential downpours or persistent (12 hours worth) of rain a day for 5-7 days - otherwise, you will still need to water it as described even if its showery/cloudy/drizzly  weather. Water in well when you plant too...

Better, obviously. to wait until autumn and plant it then, really.